# Replace data in array based on regex

Tags: php, regexp-replace

I have the next array with data (which is dynamically generated).
Now I want to do some Magic and tweak the array.

```
array(1) {
  ["table"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["header"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["c"]=>
        string(4) "Naam"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["c"]=>
        string(7) "Functie"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["c"]=>
        string(13) "Nevenfuncties"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(1) {
        ["c"]=>
        string(34) " commissies"
      }
    }
    ["caption"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["body"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["c"]=>
          string(16) "*|class:orange|*"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["c"]=>
          string(6) "dsasad"
        }
        [2]=>
        array(1) {
          ["c"]=>
          string(0) ""
        }
        [3]=>
        array(1) {
          ["c"]=>
          string(0) ""
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["c"]=>
          string(4) "brrr"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["c"]=>
          string(6) "adsdsa"
        }
        [2]=>
        array(1) {
          ["c"]=>
          string(0) ""
        }
        [3]=>
        array(1) {
          ["c"]=>
          string(0) ""
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["c"]=>
          string(6) "dsasad"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["c"]=>
          string(6) "dsadas"
        }
        [2]=>
        array(1) {
          ["c"]=>
          string(4) "dsad"
        }
        [3]=>
        array(1) {
          ["c"]=>
          string(0) ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When we look at the ['header'] it contains ['c'] (the cell data). This can be text, but also a tag.
For example: `*|class:orange|* here some text`.

Now I want to split those up and overwrite the ['c'] if it contains '*|class:orange|*'.
So when you have this:

```
   array(1) {
        ["c"]=>
        string(7) "*|class:orange|* hello"
      }
```

It would become this:

```
   array(2) {
        ["c"]=>
        string(7) "hello",
        ["class"]=>
        string(7) "orange",
      }
```

This way I could split the class and add it to the array. But I am stuck at the preg_match.

```
foreach ($table as &$row) {

    foreach ($row['header'] as &$header) {
//        $header['class'] = 123;

        preg_match('/\*\|class:([^\|])\|\*/', $header['c'], $matches);

    }
}
```

I need to do 2 things

- Add an attribute to the array ($header['class']) with the class after class:example.
- I need to replace the $header['c'] so it does not contain `*|class:orange|*` and only the rest of the text.

Comment: The pattern could be like this `\*\|class:([^\|]+)\|\*\h*(.+)` to get 2 capturing groups https://regex101.com/r/NvEU5M/1

Comment: Thank you, I have modefy it in `\*\|class:([^\|]+)\|\*\h*(.*)` so a space is not needed

Comment: You are welcome, I have added it as an update to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could for example use 2 capturing groups and use those as the values for the c and new class key.

For the second capturing group you could make sure to match at least a single non whitespace char using `\S`

Note to repeat the character class 1 or more times and you don't have to escape the pipe in the character class.

```
\*\|class:([^|]+)\|\*\h*(\S.*)
```

Or if what follows for group 2 can be optional:

```
\*\|class:([^\|]+)\|\*\h*(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MZRSMp/1)

**Explanation first pattern**

- `\*\|` Match *|
- `class:` Match literally
- `([^|]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times any char except `|`
- `\|\*\h*` Match `|*` followed by 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(\S.*)` Capture group 2, match a non whitespace char and 0+ times any char except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dguxZA/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/ULS6T)

Example code

```
$array = [
    "c" => "*|class:orange|* hello"
];

$pattern = "~\*\|class:([^|]+)\|\*\h*(\S.*)~";
foreach ($array as $key => $string) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
        $array[$key] = $matches[2];
        $array["class"] = $matches[1];
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [c] => hello
    [class] => orange
)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for regexp (yet). Tags can be found with delimiter positioning:

```
foreach ($row['header'] as &$header) {
    $str = $header['c'];

    $tagged = substr($str, 0, 2) === '*|' && $pos = strpos($str, '|* ');
    if (!$tagged) { continue; }

    [$tag, $value] = explode(':', substr($str, 2, $pos - 2));
    $header['c']  = substr($str, $pos + 3);
    $header[$tag] = $value;
}
```